# Error handling for applications in aem

Tags: error-handling, http-status-code-404, aem, multi-tenant

I am wondering about the error handling in AEM for multi-tenancy applications with different content structure. My applications steps are follows:

```
/content/firstapp/en

---- Difficulty in the multicountry and multitenancy
/content/secondapp/country-1/en
/content/secondapp/country-2/en
/content/secondapp/country-3/en

/contente/thirdapp/en

Please suggest in this case someone implemented this kind of structure in the past or have more information to do this approachae,. thanks, Sandeep
```

Answer (score 0):

First step is to have correctly setup the error handler, where in you are setting proper error code in the response status.

Sample for error handler for `404` configurations `404.jsp`

```
<%
if (com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != com.day.cq.wcm.api.WCMMode.DISABLED) {
%>
    <%@include file="/libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp"%>
<%
} else {
    response.setStatus(404);
}
%>
```

Next step is to have apache/dispatcher configured to load correct error document (configuration in Virtual host config). This way the proper loading of error page is delegated to the apache/dispatcher -

```
 <LocationMatch "^/content/secondapp/country-1/en/.*$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/country-1/not-found.html"
    ErrorDocument 500 "/country-1/error.html"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/content/secondapp/country-2/en/.*$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/country-2/not-found.html"
    ErrorDocument 500 "/country-2/error.html"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/content/secondapp/country-3/en/.*$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/country-3/not-found.html"
    ErrorDocument 500 "/country-3/error.html"
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "^/content/secondapp/country-4/en/.*$">
    ErrorDocument 404 "/country-4/not-found.html"
    ErrorDocument 500 "/country-4/error.html"
</LocationMatch>
```

Above configuration is based on the short URLs where in the pattern is 
`/content/secondapp/country-x/en/.*`  shortens `to /country-4/en/.*` and each site has its own error.html page and not-found.html